# Simple.Data can be safely used in mono today?

Tags: mono, simple.data

Some questions about Simple.Data and Mono:

Can I safely choose Simple.Data for a new project using Mono today?
There is the intention to maintain Mono compatibility in future versions?
The features are the same as the version for Windows?
Some testimony from someone who has already used in Mono?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a new official Mono build soon as part of the RC process. For now you should be able to clone the GitHub repo (http://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) and build the latest version.

Mono support is a requirement of the project, and will continue in all future versions.

Everything that works on Windows and MS.NET should work on Mono on OSX and Linux. If you find that something does not work, that is a bug and should be reported at http://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/Issues .

I have not personally got any projects using Simple.Data on Mono, so I can't offer a real testimony, but there are ~700 tests which all pass using Mono 2.10 on Mac OSX against a SQL Server DB.

Comment: Thanks so much, Mark. As soon as my project could be used as an example of good use in Mono I let you know. :)